# Как можно добраться до массива объектов (items) в JSONе, чтобы его распарсить? Используя Alamofire и SwiftyJson

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Вот тут json:

```
{
    "article": [
        {
            "header": "mindshare payment",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "Applications workforce",
                    "text": "Nulla molestiae aliquid natus libero placeat fugit recusandae tempora et."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот пример моего кода:

```
            if let result = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                let articleArray = result["article"] as? [[String: Any]],
                let main = articleArray["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for obj in main {
                    guard
                        let title = obj["title"] as? String,
                        let text = obj["text"] as? String,
                        else {
                            return
                    }
                    let struct = Articles(title: title, text: text)
                    }

                }
```

Появляется ошибка:
**Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'**

Answer (score 1):

```
request(YOUR_URL, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let yourJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if yourJSON != JSON.null {
                    self.title = yourJSON["article"]["title"].string
                    self.text = yourJSON["article"]["text"].string
                } else {
                    print("Not success: Json nil")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let result = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
        let articleArray = result["article"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        articleArray.forEach { (obj: [[String: Any]]) in
            guard let title = obj["title"] as? String,
                 let text = obj["text"] as? String,
            else { return }
            let struct = Articles(title: title, text: text)
        }
    }
```